# Enable Touchpad configuration in ubuntu 14.04 Toshiba Tecra Z40

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, toshiba

I just acquired a Toshiba Tecra Z40, it detects the touchpad as a PS2 Mouse generic. 
I would like to disable clicking by tap and enable two finger scroll.

Could you give me any clues?

Thanks in advance! 
Aram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this site:

http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_tecra_z50

> the problems I had with the touchpad not being recognized (which is an
>   issue to many) were solved by updating to kernel 3.17